# Show entered data on real time basis on other web page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a requirement to build a small application where the user will type in a text box and while he is typing the data should be displayed on real time basis on the other web page. Is there anyway I can achieve such a functionality using C#, ajax, javascript and Sql Server.

Comment: Yes, there is, good luck !

Comment: What dou you have tried?

Comment: Yes, SignalR is for this exact thing. http://signalr.net/

Comment: bind keydown/change event - make ajax call - do your query magic - send the results back - listen on your other page via a socket when event is fired - show the data

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben and Hatsjoem. I will try out your suggestions and let you know. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try exploring [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Amit. I will try it out and let you know.